# Python, "стирание" предыдущей строки

Tags: python, строки, cmd, clear

Вот напишем к примеру код:

```
while True:
    t = input("> ")
    if t == "0":
        print("Значение 0")
    elif t == "1":
        print("Значение 1")
        clearstr(5)
```

Где `clearstr()` - функция, которая будет стирать предыдущую строку через параметр `time = 5 (секунд)`

Как можно реализовать такую функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает в PyCharm

```
import time

while True:
    t = input("> ")
    if t in ["0", "1"]:
        print(f"Значение {t}", end='')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('\r', end='')
```

```
> 0
> 1
> 0
Значение 0
```

Comment: Алексей, Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться Таймером, вот вам простой и наглядный пример:

```
import threading
import os
import time

def clear_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    
threading.Timer(5, clear_console).start()

iter_i=0
while True:
    iter_i+=1
    print(f"!!!{iter_i}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Если нам нужно почистить не всю консоль, а только предыдущею строку:

```
import threading
import os
    
def clear_console():
    print("\033[F\033[K", end="", flush=True)
  # Возврат на предыдущую строку и очистка ее

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print("Первая строка")
print("Вторая строка")

threading.Timer(5, clear_console).start()

input()
```

На эту тему был неплохой ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560686/22294930).

Для PyCharm можете воспользоваться уловкой:

```
clear = "\n" * 100
print(clear)
```

Это конечно не совсем очистка, но как вариант)

Comment: У меня не стирается, в PyCharm должно работать?

Comment: Нет, стирание только в консоли.